# BindingExpression path error - 'Color' property not found on 'MyObjectsVM'

Tags: c#, binding

I have checked StackOverflow looking for the answer, and asking here is my last resort, so please do not downvote. I need an opinion of someone more experienced in databinding than me:
Here is what I want to bind:

```
<Grid x:Name="all" Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBlock Text="all"  Foreground="{Binding Color}" x:Name="allTxt" Grid.Row="0" Padding="10,21,0,0" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Tap="TextBlock_Tap_1"  />
</Grid>
```

And this is how I set DataContext of the Grid component

```
public Multiplication()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.all.DataContext = App.MyObjectsViewModel.allObjectsVisible;
}
```

Here is the constructor for MyObjectsViewModel

```
public MyObjectsViewModel(DataContextManager manager)
{
    allObjectsVisible = new allVisibleBtn() { Allvisible = true, Color = "white" };
}
```

And here is the allObjectsVisible attribute:

```
 private allVisibleBtn _allObjectsVisible;
 public allVisibleBtn allObjectsVisible
 {
    get { return _allObjectsVisible;}
    set { _allObjectsVisible= value; NotifyPropertyChanged("allObjectsVisible"); }
 }
```

And finally here is the class for allObjectsBtn:

```
public class allVisibleBtn : BaseViewModel
    {
        private bool _Allvisible;
        public bool Allvisible
        {   get { return _Allvisible; }
            set { NotifyPropertyChanging("Allvisible"); _Allvisible = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Allvisible"); }
        }

        private string _Color;
        public string Color
        {
            get { return _Color; }
            set { if (value != null) { NotifyPropertyChanging("Color"); _Color = value; } NotifyPropertyChanged("Color"); }
        }
    }
```

The expected behavior is changing textblock foreground the moment someone taps it. OFC there are some more things that are done after the tap, but nothing significant from the point of the problem. 
So please help me out, why do i get the following error:

```
`System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Color' property not found on 'Project.MyObjectsViewModel' 'Project.MyObjectsViewModel' (HashCode=50930930). BindingExpression: Path='Color' DataItem='Project.MyObjectsViewModel' (HashCode=50930930); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='allTxt'); target property is 'Foreground' (type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush')..`
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataContext of the TextBlock seems to be an instance of  `Project.MyObjectsViewModel`, and that type does not have a Color property. So you need to set the DataContext of your TextBlock to an instance of `allVisibleBtn`. Try

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Path=allObjectsVisible}" ... />
```

Once you get that working, you would need to change the type of the Color property on `allVisibleBtn`. The Foreground property of the TextBlock expects a Brush, not a string.